# Finding a seg fault in recursive code for inorder successor

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, inorder

Hey guys I'm just practicing recursive code on a binary search tree.  I'm getting a seg fault but I'm not sure where the problem is (probably something stupid staring me right in the face). I have other functions that are working fine like counting the number of nodes or counting the height of the tree.  This function in particular is giving me trouble. I'm coding in c++.

```
//wrapper function
int table::in_order_successor()
{
    node * temp;
    temp = root;
    in_order_successor(root, temp);  
}

//Find the in-order successor
int table::in_order_successor(node * root, node * temp)
{
    if(root == NULL) return 0;

    if(root->right != NULL)
             if(root->data == temp->data)
                    in_order_successor(root, temp->right);

    in_order_successor(root, temp->left);

    return temp->data;
}
```

The idea I had was to get the function to go right once from the root and then continue left as far as possible.  To get it to go right once I want to only go right if my root->data is equal to my temp->data  (the data is just a randomly generated int).

Comment: not sure if you're still following my answer.  I have edited my answer many times and hope this version works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Seg fault, you should check whether `temp` is `null`, as you code might pass `temp->right` and `temp->left` to it, which might be `null`.

```
  if(temp == NULL) return 0; // add this check
```

But there is another problem in your code: you never reuse the return value.  Then it will just iterate.  Suppose you would like to return the data stored in the leaf node after your traversal, then the code could look like this:

```
//Find the in-order successor
int table::in_order_successor(node * root, node * temp) {
  if(root == NULL) return 0;
  if(temp == NULL) return 0; // add this check

  if(root->right != NULL) {
     // check by pointer instead of the data unless each
     // node->data is unique.  Otherwise unwanted moving
     // right will occur.
     if(root == temp) {           
       if (temp->right != null) {
         // use `return` here instead of plain function call to get
         // the update of the rest of the recursion.
         return in_order_successor(root, temp->right);
       }
     }
  }

  if (temp->left != null) {
    // if have left child, return what you will find in the next step
    return in_order_successor(root, temp->left); // use return here
  } else {
    // reach the left-most leaf after first steping right at root node.
    return temp->data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding this makes the code not seg fault anymore.  That's great, but now I'm only getting the root's data returned at the end.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer.  The problem is you never use the value you returned.  You should return in_order_successor, instead of just calling it ...

Comment: This seems to work.  I'm not used to using return in the middle of functions like that, so I guess I know what I need to practice now.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2484019: you're welcomed.  There are many interesting uses of return value, such as including them in a formula like: `return foo(temp->left) + foo(temp->right)`;

Comment: @user2484019 btw, it would be my pleasure if you don't mind voting up my answer :)

Comment: I want to but I need more rep :(

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
 if(temp->left != NULL)
    in_order_successor(root, temp->left);
```

and

```
if(!temp-> left)
  return temp->data;
```

Comment: He only wants to to go right only once from the root and then continue left as far as possible, so I think the code in OP on this part might be right.